# how to change image in imageview from adapter android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i change image from adapter.
I have created a ListView and in this listview i have added dynamic item which has name and picture. I want to change the pic from that item on some logic.

adapter is created by below code

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems , R.layout.list_item, new String[] { NAME, EMPID  }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.empid });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();
```

below Code works fine if under OnItemClickListener. but i want image in at the time of rendering first view.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
if(XMLUtil.getNodeValue(group, "Gender").equalsIgnoreCase("male")){
                    view.findViewById(R.id.imageView).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.male);
                }else{
                    view.findViewById(R.id.imageView).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.female);
                }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `SimpleAdapter`, extend `BaseAdapter`, on `getView` method, do your logic right there.

Answer (score 0):

Set new image in `menuItems` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for updating your `ListView`

Comment: how to set Set new image in menuItems ?

Comment: `menuItems.get(i).put("image", R.drawable.myImage);`